# OpenMP giving inconsistent order of data

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I wrote a code in C using OpenMP, but the first four results when compiling are always in a different order and the run time only shows a value other than 0 about half of the time. Am I missing something? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

void test(int *ptr0, int *ptr1, int n)
{
    int sum=0, i;
    int id=omp_get_thread_num();

    for(i=0;i<16;i++){
        sum+=prt0[i]*ptr1[i];
    }

    printf("Sum = %d from thread %d\n",sum,id);
}

int main()
{
    int m=64, n=16, a, b;

    int** array0=calloc(m, sizeof(int*));
    for(a=0;a<m;a++){
        array0[a]=calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    }

    int** array1=calloc(m, sizeof(int*));
    for(b=0;b<m;b++){
        array1[b]=calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i=0;i<16;i++);{
        array0[i][n/2]=i;
        array1[i][n/2]=i;
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            test(array0[i],array1[i],n);
        }

    double start_time, run_time;
    start_time=omp_get_wtime();
    run_time=omp_get_wtime()-start_time;
    printf("Total run time = %.5g seconds\n", run_time);

}
```

The results are (with different variations of the first 4 lines):

```
Sum = 0 from thread 3
Sum = 1 from thread 1
Sum = 4 from thread 2
Sum = 9 from thread 3
Sum = 16 from thread 0
Sum = 25 from thread 1
Sum = 36 from thread 2
Sum = 49 from thread 3
Sum = 64 from thread 0
Sum = 81 from thread 1
Sum = 100 from thread 2
Sum = 121 from thread 3
Sum = 144 from thread 0
Sum = 169 from thread 1
Sum = 196 from thread 2
Sum = 225 from thread 3
Total run time = 3.95e-07 seconds
```

Any suggestions on how I can make the results consistent with sums being 0, 1, 4, 9, etc. and a run time that isn't 0 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you expect a long duration by requesting current start & end time in row? Didn't you want to measure something? I guess your real target was to get the start time before the loop starts and the end time after all tests are done.

The order of your outputs you can't control because you are out of control how fast your threads work. Simply put the results in an additional array and print contents in your main thread.